# startup problem with 15.04

Tags: 15.04

After loading up 15.04 my laptop boots to the login screen and, when I enter my login code, it cycles back to the beginning of the boot process.

Any ideas how to fix this - I have no access to the Internet or any of my files !!!

Comment: Can you login via the terminal (CTRL-ALT F1)?

Comment: Open a tty like @Elder Geek suggested. Are there any errors displayed there? If not check if your partitions are mounted right with `lsblk`.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> on your keyboard.

On the screen that appears, type in your username and password.

That logs you in. Next, run the command `sudo apt-get update`.

And then try to restart it afterward.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is should be posted as a comment.

Comment: @Allkill It seems unlikely this would help, as stated. Do you mean to also run `sudo apt-get upgrade`? By itself, `sudo apt-get update` only updates the locally stored *information* about what software is available to be updated and installed.

Comment: @Pabi No, even as originally written, this was an answer, not a comment. Answers that don't explain themselves enough, give only partial solutions, or are wrong [are much, *much* worse as comments than as answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2281). I recommend against advising newcomers that such posts would be considered appropriate as comments, as there is a strong community consensus that they are not.